# I want to copy the value of List<CustomType> and paste them in my console apps in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working in C# code for a asp.net mvc app. I do coding in project and when I test something I just call the models with data in another console app.

Now I have a reference of Models in Another console app. Now Can I copy the value from stacktrack ,watch & immediate windows (any of all)

What I want is I want to test it through console app. I have a add reference. I thing if I can copy the value at debug time in mvc app and paste them in console. This would be awesome.

### Do someone have idea how to do this in C# using Express Visual web developer.

I have a  asp.net mvc app. I want to copy the value of list and paste them in another console app. I feel I can do debug better.

For doing this I have add a model dll in console app. now I look for something that can gave me code that I can paste in console app. When I debug the mvc app is their any way I can copy the text or list of customobject.

I want to paste these field for testing in console app. Do someone know how I can solve this.

Comment: Do you mean the Error **StackTrace**?

Comment: @christiandev I means that I can copy the value of list and paste them in next console windows. This way I can debug it better.

Comment: Can you post an example as a screen-shot or code, as I'm not sure what this means?

Comment: When we debug app then suppose List<string> have 12 element I want to copies those and paste them in console app code for testing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to have...

1. a running webapp
2. a running console application that you start up and can use to fetch objects from the web application to print them in the console
   application for debugging

This is completely wrong. To do this, it would be necessary to include some very complicated stuff to serialize all the stuff, sending them over a socket and such. You definitely don't want to do that. What you should do is:

- The best thing would be if you figured out how to use the Visual Studio Debugger. Look for online tutorials. With this you can stop your webapp during runtime and inspect all the variables (including lists of strings and their contents) by hovering over the source code.
- If you don't understand or don't want to use the debugger, it sounds like you're best off using the foreach loop and the Console.WriteLine method in the code that you want to debug. Like this:

  ```
  foreach (var str in listOfStrings)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(str);
  }
  ```

  You can then in Visual Studio open the output view, where all the Console output is shown.